# Calling JDBC to impala/hive from within a spark job and loading a table

Tags: apache-spark, impala

I am trying to write a spark job in java that would open a jdbc connection with Impala and let me load a table and perform other operations.

How do I do this? Any example would be of great help. Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK Impala uses Hive Metastore, so why not use a native HiveContext???

Answer (score 0):

If using JDBC is a must, what you might want to try is execute a query in spark driver.

E.g. using impyla for python, you'd get a result from impala in a normal list of tuples. Later you can convert this result to spark rdd with parallelize().